# Error publishing an image to Openshift (minishift)

Tags: openshift, fabric8

I'm trying to publish an image to Openshift using maven fabric8 plugin and got the following error:

Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Can't instantiate binary build, due to error reading/writing stream. Can be caused if the output stream was closed by the server.

Below is the complete stack trace. Any clue that can help me?
Thanks in advance

``
[INFO] F8: Starting Build hello-microservice-s2i
[ERROR] F8: Failed to execute the build [Unable to build the image using the OpenShift build service]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:19 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-02T22:06:21-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.30:build (fmp) on project hello-microservice: Failed to execute the build: Unable to build the image using the OpenShift build service: Can't instantiate binary build, due to error reading/writing stream. Can be caused if the output stream was closed by the server. stream was reset: NO_ERROR -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.30:build (fmp) on project hello-microservice: Failed to execute the build
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to execute the build
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.buildAndTag (BuildMojo.java:245)
at io.fabric8.maven.docker.BuildMojo.executeInternal (BuildMojo.java:44)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.executeInternal (BuildMojo.java:222)
at io.fabric8.maven.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:223)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: io.fabric8.maven.core.service.Fabric8ServiceException: Unable to build the image using the OpenShift build service
at io.fabric8.maven.core.service.openshift.OpenshiftBuildService.build (OpenshiftBuildService.java:114)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.buildAndTag (BuildMojo.java:242)
at io.fabric8.maven.docker.BuildMojo.executeInternal (BuildMojo.java:44)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.executeInternal (BuildMojo.java:222)
at io.fabric8.maven.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:223)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Can't instantiate binary build, due to error reading/writing stream. Can be caused if the output stream was closed by the server.
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable (KubernetesClientException.java:62)
at io.fabric8.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl$1.writeTo (BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:260)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept (CallServerInterceptor.java:62)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at io.fabric8.openshift.client.internal.OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.intercept (OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.java:64)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain (RealCall.java:185)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute (RealCall.java:69)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse (OperationSupport.java:377)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse (OperationSupport.java:359)
at io.fabric8.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl.fromInputStream (BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:274)
at io.fabric8.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl.fromFile (BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:231)
at io.fabric8.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl.fromFile (BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:68)
at io.fabric8.maven.core.service.openshift.OpenshiftBuildService.startBuild (OpenshiftBuildService.java:319)
at io.fabric8.maven.core.service.openshift.OpenshiftBuildService.build (OpenshiftBuildService.java:104)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.buildAndTag (BuildMojo.java:242)
at io.fabric8.maven.docker.BuildMojo.executeInternal (BuildMojo.java:44)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.executeInternal (BuildMojo.java:222)
at io.fabric8.maven.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:223)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: NO_ERROR
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.checkOutNotClosed (Http2Stream.java:567)
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.emitFrame (Http2Stream.java:501)
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.write (Http2Stream.java:481)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments (RealBufferedSink.java:171)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeAll (RealBufferedSink.java:99)
at io.fabric8.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl$1.writeTo (BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:258)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept (CallServerInterceptor.java:62)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at io.fabric8.openshift.client.internal.OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.intercept (OpenShiftOAuthInterceptor.java:64)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain (RealCall.java:185)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute (RealCall.java:69)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse (OperationSupport.java:377)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse (OperationSupport.java:359)
at io.fabric8.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl.fromInputStream (BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:274)
at io.fabric8.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl.fromFile (BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:231)
at io.fabric8.openshift.client.dsl.internal.BuildConfigOperationsImpl.fromFile (BuildConfigOperationsImpl.java:68)
at io.fabric8.maven.core.service.openshift.OpenshiftBuildService.startBuild (OpenshiftBuildService.java:319)
at io.fabric8.maven.core.service.openshift.OpenshiftBuildService.build (OpenshiftBuildService.java:104)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.buildAndTag (BuildMojo.java:242)
at io.fabric8.maven.docker.BuildMojo.executeInternal (BuildMojo.java:44)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.executeInternal (BuildMojo.java:222)
at io.fabric8.maven.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:223)
at io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: Hello, I'm from fabric8 team. Fabric8 Maven Plugin has been rebranded to [OpenShift Maven Plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/docs/openshift-maven-plugin). You can easily migrate to jkube using `mvn org.eclipse.jkube:openshift-maven-plugin:migrate`. Do you face similar issue when you use Eclipse JKube OpenShift Maven Plugin?

Comment: Do you have some reproducer project which we can try out?